# Add a URL to a custom user profile property

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I have added a new property : "Edit notification and activity stream settings". using power shell

I want to give a url as the value of this property. How to achieve this?
When I give the url in the description field it comes below the text box of the property which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Feeling stupid ! After a few trials i got the script to update the property value.
Here it is

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server") 
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles") 
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
#############################################

write-host "======== Set URL for Notification Settings =========" 

##########CODE########################
# Load SharePoint.PowerShell snapin 
if (!(Get-PSSnapin | ?{$_.name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell'})) 
{ 
    if(Get-PSSnapin -registered | ?{$_.name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell'}) 
    { 
        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
        write-host "Loading Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell in session" 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        write-host "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is not registered with the system." 
        break 
    } 
} 
else 
{ 
    write-host "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is already loaded" 
} 

$stackTrace = ""
$ScriptPath = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$logcsv = $ScriptPath + "\UpdateURL_log.csv"        #output csv format
Set-Content -Path $logcsv -Value $header -Encoding UTF8

#Function to get service context
function Get- SPServiceContext([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceApplication] $profileApp)
{
 $profileApp = @(Get-SPServiceApplication | ? {$_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Service Application"})[0]
 return [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($profileApp.ServiceApplicationProxyGroup,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteSubscriptionIdentifier]::Default)
  }

  $serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext
$profileManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext)

$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()
$url = "http://someurl"

 Try
{
foreach ($userProfile in $profiles) {
$u = $userProfile.Item("Accountname")
$u = $u.ToString().ToLower()

if($u.StartsWith("abc") -eq $true){
    Write-host "Setting value for: " $u
     "Setting value for: " + $u | Add-Content -Path $logcsv 
    $userProfile["ActivitySettings1"].Value =  $url     
    $userProfile.Commit()
}
}
}
   catch{
     Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Source
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.Message
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_.Exception.StackTrace
$_.Exception.Source + ";"+ $_.Exception.Message +";" + $_.Exception.StackTrace  | Add-Content -Path $logcsv
}
write-host "-------------- Finished Script --------------"
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you need that?

Comment: The requirement is to show a url for a property"Edit your NG settings";which again is a custom property. The user can navigate to the url and edit the settings.

Comment: Can't they do that by just editing their profile? Why do you need the URL?

Comment: actually, for a property the value should be a url which should redirect the user to another page which contains another set of news gator properties(a 3rd party pluglin). That url would be same for every user, just a query string:ngSetting=1 appened to the edit profile url

Comment: So, if it's the same URL, couldn't you just add the URL to the page?